# SQL Server trigger to update row and save old version

Tags: sql-server

I setup the below trigger to save the old version of a modified row into an "Archive" table. It works fine as long as the commented part stays commented. Once I uncomment the UPDATE part, the trigger saves the row as it is AFTER the update, instead of BEFORE the update. What should I change ?

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[TRG_AFTER_UPDATE_Test]
ON [dbo].[Test]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO  dbo.TestArchive(
                        [CustId]
                        ,[CustName]
                        ,[SomeValue]
                        ,[Modified]
                        ,[ModifiedBy]
                        )
            SELECT     s.[CustId]
                        ,s.[CustName]
                        ,s.[SomeValue]
                        ,s.[Modified]
                        ,s.[ModifiedBy]
            FROM    dbo.Test s
            INNER JOIN deleted d ON s.CustId = d.CustId

--here is the part that makes the INSERT behave badly
/*
        UPDATE  dbo.Test
            SET     ModifiedBy = USER_NAME(),
                    Modified = GETDATE()
            FROM    dbo.Test s
            INNER JOIN Inserted i ON s.CustId = i.CustId
*/

END
```

Comment: Why you update your main table (on which update trigger defined, i.e dbo.Test) inside trigger code, you can update it outside through update query.

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari because this table will be updated by business using MS-Access and we want to enforce a **reliable** way to record when and by whom the change was made, PLUS an archive with revisions history

Comment: try inserting the data from the deleted table and not the actual table. change the columns in your select from s.[column name] to d.[column name].

Comment: @ZoharPeled  it works perfectly. Make it an answer, so I can mark it as such pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try inserting the data from the deleted table and not the actual table. Change the columns in your select from `s.[column name]` to `d.[column name]`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an infinite loop going on here with the update...

Your trigger is set to the update event of dbo.Test, and within that trigger you are updating the dbo.Test table on which the trigger is set, which in turn fires the update trigger ad infinitum....

I am not sure if it would work by disabling the trigger within itself before performing the update and then re-enabling it afterwards.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189748.aspx